# Formula for calculating sample size for comparison of two proportions

Tags: self-study, proportion, statistical-power

The formula for calculating sample size in a two sided hypothesis on two proportions is:

$$n_1\ge \frac{\left(Z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot\frac{S_0}{S_1}+Z_{1-\beta}\right)^2S_1^2}{(p_1-p_2)^2}$$

I'm asked to explain why in one sided hypothesis instead of $Z_{1-\alpha/2}$ we have $Z_{1-\alpha}$, with regards to the different variables in the formula. I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. Can you explain how the different variables relate to the $Z$ property when converting from a two-sided hypothesis to a one sided hypothesis?